# JavaScript not working within modal in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I am using some JavaScript code in a Shiny app in order to style a textAreaInput inside a modal. My code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)

codeJS <- "
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event)
  {                
    function init (inputID) 
    {
      var text = document.getElementById(inputID);
      text.style.color = 'blue';
    };
  
    init('textField');
  })"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(HTML(codeJS)),
  actionButton(inputId="openModal", label="Open modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  observeEvent(input$openModal,
  {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      textAreaInput(inputId = "textField", label = "window", value = "ABC")
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When `textAreaInput(inputId = "textField", label = "window", value = "ABC")` is put outside of the modal, the JavaScript code works fine. But the JavaScript code has no effect on the inputs within the modal.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can include the CSS code inline as shown below.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  #tags$script(HTML(codeJS)),
  actionButton(inputId="openModal", label="Open modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  observeEvent(input$openModal,
               {
                 showModal(modalDialog(
                   textAreaInput(inputId = "textField", label = "window", value = "ABC"),
                   tags$head(tags$style("#textField{color: red;
                                 font-size: 20px;
                                 font-style: italic;
                                 }" ))
                 ))
               })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For inline javascript, try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId="openModal", label="Open modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  observeEvent(input$openModal,
               {
                 showModal(modalDialog(
                   textAreaInput(inputId = "textField", label = "window", value = "ABC"),
                   tags$script(HTML('document.getElementById("textField").style.color = "red"'))
                 ))
               })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You brought me on the right track. But I would like to use JavaScript instead of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

YBS brought me on the right track. With using JavaScript instead of CSS the code becomes like this:

```
codeJS <- "
  function init (inputID) 
  {
    var text = document.getElementById(inputID);
        text.style.color     = 'red';
        text.style.fontSize  = '20px';
        text.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
  };
  
  init('textField');"

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId="openModal", label="Open modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  observeEvent(input$openModal,
  {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      textAreaInput(inputId = "textField", label = "window", value = "ABC"),
      tags$script(HTML(codeJS))
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Could you tell what is going wrong when you run the script?

Comment: Your answer works fine.  Sorry, I had not copied the new codeJS script, as I thought your original codeJS did not change.